# Is Segmentation Fault a.k.a Bus Error, an error or a fault?

Tags: c, linux, windows, segmentation-fault

I'm confused. Segmentation Fault is also known as Bus Error. So how should it be categorized, an error or a fault. In windows term, it is also known as Illegal operation error. In my opinion it should be called an error, since it is caused by an underlying bug or a hardware fault.

I think an error is the manifestion of a fault rather the other way round. I am following the classification given by "Basic Concepts and Taxonomy of Dependable and Secure Computing". What do you guys think?

Comment: Someone needs to paint that [bike shed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_Law_of_Triviality).

Comment: I think you already made this question not an hour ago.

Comment: hexa, yes I asked it but some people thought it as a homework, which is not. I am really confused about the classification of an error and fault. Some say error causes fault, other say fault causes error! really confusing, isn't it?

Comment: Should this be moved to the English Language SO? After all, it's about the semantic difference between "Error" and "Fault". Most non-native speaker would not be able to tell the difference between those two, so the discussion is only of interest for those with a Master in English.

Comment: I don't know why are you guys making a fun of this. The differentiation between the two is important when studying dependable and secure computing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A segmentation fault is not quite the same thing as a bus-error.  A segmentation fault is an error created by the OS-runtime that occurs when the running software attempts to access memory outside of an allowed memory-page.  This is typically in relation to a protected memory OS that only allows user-mode processes to access memory in certain segments, and makes other memory segments restricted to higher-privileged kernel-processes.  A bus-error on the other-hand is a hardware error that occurs when the software attempts to make a memory access that cannot be made by the hardware.  The two types of errors can semantically coincide for instance on a processor architecture like x86 when a memory access is made, and the processor throws a general-protection fault or some other processor exception.  But you can also have segmentation faults that are not caused by processor exceptions.

Comment: so you are saying, its an error, not a fault?

Comment: A "bus-error" typically comes from throwing a processor-exception ... i.e., mis-aligned memory access, general protection fault, etc.  Notice that a bus-error is not just from a "fault".  In other words bus-errors encompass certain types of hardware-related faults as well as general memory-hardware errors.  A segmentation fault on the other-hand is software-related and comes from accessing memory outside of the allowed bounds that that OS-runtime has given to the user-mode process.

Comment: @MetalicPriest you really should use Google and use some CS textbooks. This is pretty basic stuff and it's covered in a lot of OS design literature. ERROR == FAULT for all intents and purposes.

Comment: Adam, I don't think so. I'm following the taxonomy given in the paper "Basic Concepts and Taxonomy of Dependable and Secure Computing" and it clearly differentiates the two.

Comment: IIRC fault is an unwanted condition that is not yet visible to the outside observer. Whereas error is defined as a visible fault. Whether a segmentation fault leads to an error is os dependant on how he handles it. Even on the software or as how you define the observer. A segmentation fault is AFAIK not known as a bus error. I'm hearing this for the first time and i do study CS with emphasis on OS and embedded HW.